# Maple Code for Ricci Flow

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, maple, ricci-flow

I am trying to generate a Maple Simulation for Ricci Flow assuming general Solids of Revolution and such. I assume that there is a surface with the following parametrization:
$$S:\left\{\begin{matrix}x=R(z,t)\cos\theta \\y=R(z,t)\sin\theta\\ z=z\end{matrix}\phantom{..}\begin{matrix}\theta\in[0..2\pi] \\ z\in[0..1]\end{matrix}\right.$$

And want to see how the surface is deformed by Ricci Flow. My Maple Code is as such:

-I define my x,y,&z coordinates

-I define the tangent vectors

-I define the metric tensor

-I define the Christoffel Symbols

-I define the Ricci Tensor

-I attempt at pdsolving the equation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{i j}=-2R_{i j}$$

[image: Maple Instructions]

Everything goes lovely, but upon the execution of the final line, I get the following message:

"***Error, (in pdsolve/numeric/plot) unable to compute solution for t>HFloat(0.0):
Newton iteration is not converging***"

Can someone please help me as to the fail in the way I set up my Maple Code? Thanks a lot everyone.